# labels data type = 19 is not supported

Tags: opencv

```
  1 Ids,faces= getImageWithID('dataSet')
  2 recognizer.train(faces, np.array(Ids))
  3 recognizer.save('trainner/trainner.yml')
```

TypeError: labels data type = 19 is not supported

Comment: you need to convert your labels to integer before passing it to an array

Comment: Thanks Jeru Luke, i got it

Comment: You need to assign a single integer for every *unique* ID. You can use the [encoder available on scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Answer (score 1):

That's because "Ids" is a string.
".train" will only accept an integer.

Comment: The exact same answer was given in a comment last year.

Comment: I'm sure it was! It's a pretty common problem.